# ArcGIS query specific character(s) in specific part of a field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, query

Using ArcGIS 10.2.2, I have a string field in an SDE attribute table.  I need help creating a query to select all records that have a zero in the 6th and 7th character of the field (i.e 1995-0023A).  To help me better understand this type of query, I would also like to be able to see a query that selects records with a zero in just the 6th character of the field.  I can then use the "and" clause and duplicate it to select the 7th character as well.

I've tried variations of  `"FIELD1" LIKE '%00_______'` but it doesn't select records with the double zeroes in the correct place in the string.

Comment: I've tried variations of  "FIELD1" LIKE '%00_______' but it doesn't select records with the double zeroes in the correct place in the string.

Comment: Something like `"FIELD1" LIKE '_____00%'` ? That would use five character wildcards, then your two zeros, then another wildcard for the rest of the string.  What type of database are these in?  SQL Server, Oracle, something else?  Please [edit] your question to include the info from your comment above, and details about your database (version release etc.)

Comment: "field_name" LIKE '%00%' this will return all fields with double zeros next to each other doesnt use the 6th or 7th position if that helps.

Comment: An underscore `_` is used in some databases as a single character place wildcard.  A percent `%` is wildcard for all character places.

Comment: Thanks guys, looks like I had the the query reversed.  Midavalo's suggestion worked:  FIELD1 LIKE '_____00%'.  Its an Oracle DB.

Comment: There is no such thing as "an SDE attribute field". SDE no longer exists. Esri does not make an RDBMS or NoSQL database product.  The SQL query applied in an enterprise geodatabase connection will *always* be executed by the RDBMS, so you need to specify what that database product is *in the question*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An underscore `_` is used in some databases as a single character place wildcard. A percent `%` is wildcard for all character places.

Therefore, something like `"FIELD1" LIKE '_____00%'` should work, depending on the type of database.  That would use five character wildcards, then your two zeros, then another wildcard for the rest of the string.

Comment: would this work in MS SQL Server DB as well?

Comment: @Joe Yes it should - I have used this method for similar queries in the past in SQL Server, but I cannot test this right now.

Answer (score 3):

The following would select all records that have a zero in the 6th character position as well as in the 7th character position.

```
FIELDNAME like '_____0%' and FIELDNAME like '______0%'
```

There are five underscores preceding the zero in the first part of the expression and then six underscores preceding the zero in the second part. The underscore is a 'wildcard' that requires any character to be present (can be a space, a number, a letter, a symbol, etc.). The percent (%) wildcard allows anything to follow (also allows nothing to follow - does not require any character).

A more succinct way to query this would be

```
FIELDNAME like '_____00%'
```

Answer (score -1):

This is RDBMS dependent, though the following should work in most:

SUBSTRING(fieldname, 6, 2) = '00'

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Have you had this work successfully?  In my experience the `SUBSTRING()` never worked in ArcMap's limited SQL.  Is this where you use it, or do you use this elsewhere?  Could you [edit] your answer to expand on this?

Comment: The OP stated this was in SDE, not a file geodatabase, mdb, or shapefile.  SDE dictates an RDBMS.  The ArcMap query is based upon the where portion of the SQL, based on the particular RDBMS where the SDE exists (important to know what type of database the data is in, as syntax can differ).  Yes, I've had this perform successfully numerous times in my 20+ years as an SDE Administrator.  I've thrown this in as an option, as not all RDBMS's will utilize the '_' option.  My solution is simplistic and arguably old, but it works in an SDE environment.

Comment: I asked as I had tested this last week and it didn't work. I may have done it wrong, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: In SDE?  If so, which RDBMS does your SDE sit on?  Truly, I am curious, as the RDBMS environments intrigue me, particularly for differences.  I tested it (successful on Oracle and SQL Server) before posting as well.  SUBSTRING will be invalid for shapefiles.  It will work for file geodatabases.

Comment: btw, Oracle's syntax is SUBSTR.